# proving $B$ is not compact in $(C[0,1],d^*)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

from Topology Without Tears:

Let $(C[0,1],d^*)$ be the metric with $d^*(f,g)=sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in[0,1]\} \forall f,g\in C[0,1]$

Let $B=\{f:f\in C[0,1]\ and\ d^*(f,0)\leq 1\} $ Where $0$ denotes the constant function from $[0,1]\ into\ \mathbb{R}$ which maps every element to zero.

(i)Verify that $B$ is closed and bdd in $(C[0,1],d^*)$

(ii)Prove that $B$ is not compact(Hint:let $\{B_i:i\in I\}$ be the family of all open balls of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ in $(C[0,1],d^*)$Then $\{B_i:i\in I\}$ is an open covering of $B$.Suppose there exists a finite subcovering $B_1,B_2,...,B_N$.Consider the $(N+1)$ functions $f_\alpha:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_\alpha(x)=sin(2^{N-\alpha}.\pi x),\alpha=1,2,...,N+1$

(a)Verify that each $f_\alpha \in B$

(b)Observing that $f_{N+1}(1)=1\ and\ f_m(1)=0 \forall m\leq N$,deduce that if $f_{N+1}\in B_1\ then\ f_m\notin B_1,m=1,2,...N$

I am facing issues while doing the (b) part.I mean I can see $f_{N+1}(1)=1\ and\ f_m(1)=0 \forall m\leq N$.But how to prove that if $f_{N+1}\in B_1\ then\ f_m\notin B_1,m=1,2,...N$?I don't know much about $B_1$ just it is a open ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$.But what is the center of that open ball ,I don't know.Please tell me how should I use the given information to deduce that ?
Any hint will be very useful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Because of the value at 1, the distance between $f_{N+1}$ and $f_m$ is at least 1, so they can't be both contained in a open ball of radius $1/2$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $m\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ and $f_{N+1},f_m\in B_1$. Let $g$ be the centre of $B_1$. We don’t need to know what $g$ is to know that $d^*(g,f_{N+1})<\frac12$ and $d^*(g,f_m)<\frac12$, so

$$d^*(f_{N+1},f_m)\le d^*(g,f_{N+1})+d^*(g,f_m)<\frac12+\frac12=1\,.$$

But you know that in fact $d^*(f_{N+1},f_m)\ge 1$ (why?), so this is a contradiction, and $f_{N+1}$ and $f_m$ therefore cannot both be in $B_1$.